# Spring Data Rest override controller for Templated Link

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST to expose various domain objects as resources.

```
@Entity
class Person() {
    //fields
}

public interface PersonRepository implemets PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

So now `/persons` will be mapped to the repository methods.

Let's say I want to override the GET method. So I do:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/persons")
public class PersonController {

    private PersonRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAll(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler<Person> assembler) {

        Page<Student> page = repository.findAll();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(assembler.toResource(page));

    }
}
```

Ok so when I hit `http://localhost:8080/persons`, as expected it will be handled by the `PersonController::getAll` method.

It will provide me with this JSON

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/persons{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "persons": [
      {
        "active": true,
        "email": "mail@mail.com",
        "name": "myname",
        "phoneNumber": "1234-456",
        "surname": "mysurname",
        "userName": "username"
      }
    ]
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

However, if I click the `self` link the response will *NOT* be handled from my custom controller but from the original `@RepositoryRestController` of `SDR`.

Is there a way I can configure the custom controller to also include handle templated hrefs?

Comment: Check out tutorial for [Spring HATEOAS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/) to understand how to generate and use links for your own controller

Comment: I know how to generate and create links. The problem is that
`http://localhost:8080/api/persons` is handled by my custom controller while `http://localhost:8080/api/persons{?page,size,sort}` is handled by the SDR controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://localhost:8080/persons` vs `http://localhost:8080/api/persons`

add `/api` to your controller requestmapping to overwrite the SDR controller